# Having trouble conceptualizing logic

Tags: arrays, lua, logic

I'm fairly new to Lua and i'm trying to recreate a playing card game (standard deck of 52 + 2 Jokers). I play this in real life with real cards with my 5 year old child to improve her concentration.

However, i'm having a lot of issues recreating some of the player logic.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance for reading.

**The issue I'm facing is with ending a player's turn on the right amount of cards.**

Here is how the game goes (in real life):

It is a 2 player game.

These are the "special" cards and their values:

- The value of a Joker is 5
- The value of an Ace (any suit) is 4
- The value of a King (any suit) is 3
- The value of a Queen (any suit) is 2
- The value of a Jack (any suit) is 1

The value of any other card not listed above is also 1 (or no value)

Essentially the suit doesn't matter.

Each player draws one card at a time from their pile and places them on the table.

> Example:  Player 1 draws 4 of Spades. Not a special card. Next player
>   draws. Player 2 draws 3 of Hearts. Not a special card. Next player
>   draws. Player 1 draws 6 of Clubs. Not a special card. Next player
>   draws.

IF a player draws one of the special cards, then the opposite player has to start drawing cards equal to the value of the special card.

> Example Round::
>
> Player 1 draws 4-Spades. Not a special card. Now player2 draws 1.
>
> Player 2 draws 3-Hearts. Not a special card. Now player1 draws 1.
>
> Player 1 draws King-Clubs. This is a special card. Now player2 has to draw 3.
>
> Player 2 draws 4-Hearts.
>
> Player 2 draws 8-Spades.
>
> Player 2 draws 10-Diamonds.
>
> **Player 1 wins and takes all 6 cards.**

At that point the Round is complete and the cards go to the bottom of his/her deck.

The winner then starts a new round by throwing down the next card in his/her deck. Same as above.

IF while drawing those cards, you happen to draw another special card, then the opposite player starts throwing down cards of that value.

> Example Round::
>
> Player 1 draws 4-Spades. Not a special card. Now player2 draws 1.
>
> Player 2 draws King-Clubs. This is a special card. Now player1 has to draw 3.
>
> Player 1 draws 4-Hearts.
>
> Player 1 draws Ace-Diamonds. This is a special card. Now player2 has to draw 4.
>
> Player 2 draws 10-Diamonds.
>
> Player 2 draws 10-Hearts.
>
> Player 2 draws Jack-Clubs. This is a special card. Now player1 has to draw 1.
>
> Player 1 draws 3-Spades.
>
> **Player 2 wins and takes all 8 cards.**

This happens back and forth until any one Player looses all their cards. This game could last 5 min or go on for hours depending on the cards.

Now that you know how it's supposed to play, can someone help formulate some logic for it?

Here is what I have so far. Im only posting the main functions which handle the logic. The sub functions which do the work are all defined and working.

Also note, player2 is automatically playing for now.

```
function player1Plays()
  addCards(cardTable,player1Hand[1],countHand(cardTable)+1)
  cardsOnTable = countHand(cardTable)
  removeCards(player1Hand,1)
 end

function player2Plays()
  addCards(cardTable,player2Hand[1],countHand(cardTable)+1)
  cardsOnTable = countHand(cardTable)
  removeCards(player2Hand,1)
end

function checkCard(card)
  valueOfCard = 1
  isSpecialCard = false
  if string.sub(card,1,1) == "A" then
    valueOfCard = 4
    isSpecialCard = true 
  end
  if string.sub(card,1,1) == "K" then
    valueOfCard = 3
    isSpecialCard = true
  end
  if string.sub(card,1,1) == "Q" then
    valueOfCard = 2
    isSpecialCard = true
  end
  if string.sub(card,1,1) == "J" then 
    valueOfCard = 1 
    isSpecialCard = true
  end
  if card == "1J" then 
    valueOfCard = 5 
    isSpecialCard = true
  end
  if card == "2J" then 
    valueOfCard = 5 
    isSpecialCard = true
  end
end

function checkPlayer1Turn()

    if valueOfCard == 1 then
        if not(isSpecialCard) then
            myTurn = false
            p2Turn = true
        elseif isSpecialCard == true then -- then its a Jack
            myTurn = true
            p2Turn = false
        end
    end

end



function checkPlayer2Turn()

    if valueOfCard == 1 then
        if not(isSpecialCard) then
            myTurn = true
            p2Turn = false
        elseif isSpecialCard ==  true then -- then its a Jack
            myTurn = false
            p2Turn = true
        end
    end
end 


function pushPlayerButton( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        audio.play( clickSound )
    end

    if event.phase == "ended" then

        if not(myTurn) then

          print("not your turn")      

          player2Plays()

        else

          player1Plays() -- play a card

          checkCard(playerHand[cardsOnTable]) 

          checkPlayerTurn()

          showScore()

        end
    end
end
```

Where im really stumbling is at the `checkPlayer1Turn()` and `checkPlayer2Turn()` functions for anything more than the card value of 1.

I don't know how let player1 keep drawing more cards till either the correct count is reached or interrupt that and switch to player 2 if a special card is drawn.

Comment: use pen an paper and draw flow charts. translating a working flow chart into Lua is trivial

Comment: @Piglet, thanks for the reply. That's exactly what im having trouble with for those functions. I seem to be having "writers block" for some reason.

Comment: I don't even understand your game. is there some official name? what makes people win rounds?

Comment: @Piglet I understand. Unfortunately, this is a home-brew game we just play between ourselves. Thanks for trying though :)